# Pseudo-Droz-Farny circles

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, elementary-proofs, triangles

I would like to present a construction of 2 circles. These 2 circles are somewhat similar in appearance to the well known ***[Droz-Farny circles](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FirstDroz-FarnyCircle.html)*** that can be drawn for every isogonal conjugate pairs of points.

*A'B'C'* is the pedal triangle with respect to some point *D*. *O* - is the circumcenter of the pedal triangle.  *A'',B'',C'*' are the midpoints of the sides of the pedal triangle.    *A''', B''', C'''* are the midpoints of the segments *AO, BO, CO*.

When *D* is the incenter or the circumcenter of the triangle *ABC*, quadrilaterals *A''A'''C''C''',   B''B'''C''C''',   A''A'''B''B'''* are cyclic. Let *Ob, Oa, Oc* be the circumcenters of these 3 quadrilaterals.

For *D = X(3)*  [six point circle proceeds](https://www.geogebra.org/m/ft2jxdgg) by drawing circles with centers at *Oa, Ob, Oc* and passing through the circumcenter. Its center is the midpoint of *X(3)* and *X(5)* - the point ***X(140)*** in the ETC:
[image: First Pseudo-Droz-Farny circle]
(By the way lines *A'''Oa, B'''Ob, C'''Oc*, always intersect at some unknown center *X*. And  *X(18282)* is the circumcenter of the triangle *OaObOc*.)

For *D = X(1)*  [six point circle proceeds](https://www.geogebra.org/geometry/zuvuyphy) by drawing circles with centers at *Oa, Ob, Oc* and passing through the incenter. Its center is the midpoint of *X(1)* and *X(3)* - that is known as the point ***X(1385)*** in the ETC:

[image: Second Pseudo-Droz-Farny circle]

(By the way, if *JaJbJc* is the excentral triangle of *ABC* triangle, lines *JaOa, JbOb, JcOc* always intersect each other at some unknown point *X* that belongs to the line *X(1)X(3)*. Also OaA', ObB', OcC' always intersect at some other uncatalogued point.)

- **Does any known Kimberling triangle center belong to either of these green 6 point circles?**
- [*When D is the incenter or the circumcenter of the triangle ABC, quadrilaterals A''A'''C''C''', B''B'''C''C''', A''A'''B''B''' are cyclic.]*
  **Is it true only for *D = X(1)* and *D = X(3)*** **?**  That would make our pair of 'Pseudo Droz-Farny' circles the only one in existence...

Comment: and of course perhaps a better name might be suggested)   I chose this name only because the real First Droz-Farny circle can be constructed with the help of 3 circles passing through the circumcenter. This is actually the only thing they have in common.